# Sentence misinterpretation

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-より

I'm trying to understand what I misunderstand with this sentence example from jisho:

> 彼らのコミュニケーションは我々が考えてきたものよりはるかに複雑かもしれません。

I thought of it as roughly

> their communication, being we have come to think its far from to being difficult

Which is wrong.

I think what I've got wrong is よりはるか…しれません but i'm not sure.

The translation given on jisho is

> Their communication may be much more complex than we thought.

I've noted より is a particle so I will start there and see what it does to clause etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting はるかに

> [彼らのコミュニケーション] は [我々が考えてきたもの] より [複雑] かもしれません。

is roughly of the form

> [A] は [B] より [C] だ
>   [A] is more [C] than [B]

Putting the adverb はるかに back in and replacing だ (is) by かもしれません (might be), we get

> 彼らのコミュニケーションは我々が考えてきたものよりはるかに複雑かもしれません。
>   Their communication might be far more complex than we thought.

Comment: thanks for the input mate. 
I won't say i have it 100% but i can see where to focus.

Comment: If you can take away the basic structure for より from this (second blockquote), you're in a good position to understand sentences similar to this one.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Any thoughts on why 我々が考えてきた is nominalised with もの? I thought that was for tangible things, but 'communication' sounds like an abstract concept to me.

Answer (score 2):

I like to think of より as the “compared to” tag (like how に comes after the location, so it is the location tag), so this sentence is “Compared to what we thought, it was more complex”.